# Intellij idea how to automatically fill in bug tips, which shortcut keys?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I want to automatically fill in the missing braces with shortcuts. Does Intellij idea have such shortcuts?
[***Just like in the figure***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fndep.png)

Comment: Normally IDEA will add the closing brace as soon as you hit enter after that. Did you accidently disable that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the "complete statement" shortcut: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The result depends on the current context (language, place...). It can add semicolons, braces, parehtheses...

Comment: Thanks, according to this method I solved the problem